# Does this break the pre-image resistance of the hash function?

Tags: hash, one-way-function, preimage-resistance

Supposing a secure hash function $f(\cdot): \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ satisfies pre-image resistance.

That is, given a hash value $y$ it should be difficult to find any message $x$ such that $y = f(x)$ within $O(2^{n})$ efforts.

The question is:

Given $y \in \{0,1\}^n$, if we find $x_1,x_2$ such that $f(x_1) + Rf(x_2) = y$, can we say that we break the  pre-image resistance?, where $R$ is a positive integer.

Comment: An interesting result of this $f(x_1) + Rf(x_2) = y$ is one gets pre-image of $f(x_1)  = y + Rf(x_2)$ or $Rf(x_2) = y+ f(x_1) $ but that doesn't help to find arbitrary since we don't have the control,

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, I hope this result can solve the problem.

Comment: Hint: assume $f$ is an ideal hash function (thus collision-resistant by your definition). For any fixed $R$, find an algorithm of cost less than $O(2^n)$ that, given $y \in \{0,1\}^n$, finds $x_1,x_2$ such that $f(x_1) + Rf(x_2) = y$. Then conclude.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117542/discussion-on-question-by-yad50968-does-this-break-the-pre-image-resistance-of-t).